# Unique min-cut means unique max flow?

Tags: graphs, network-flow

This is not a home work question.

Is that correct to say in a flow network, if min cut is unique then max flow must also be unique?

Assume we have two max flow in a network. Then for each max flow, we can get a min cut and they are surely different.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2):

I do not agree with the downvoters of your question. This questions seems like a legit misunderstanding of the statement of the [min-cost-max-flow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).

The theorem states that the **value** of the sum of edge weights in a minimum $s$-$t$ cut of a graph is equal to the **value** of the maximum $s$-$t$ flow in the graph interpreted as a flow network. It does not establish a one-to-one correspondence between flows and cuts.

In fact, this correspondence cannot be established in general. Here is a counter example of an unweighted undirected graph (all weights/capacities are unit):

[image: Graph]

$1$-$5$ max-flow/min-cut is equal to one. While there is a single minimum cut ({1 - 2}). There are a lot of possible maximum flows (take the unit of flow entering 2 and distribute it between 3 and 4 as you like).